# How to configure sshd to have both ssh and sftp connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, sftp

I have two Linux machines. One of them must be a sftp server. I added the following lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
#SFTP server configuration                                                 
Match Group root                                                           
        ChrootDirectory /share                                               
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

So now I can put and get files over sftp, but when I try to connect with my sftp server over ssh I get the following error:

> This service allows sftp connections only.

What should I do to enable both sftp and ssh to root?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Allow root to access the remote system? You really do not want to do that.
There should however, be a setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
# PermitRootLogin yes|no
```

It's all in the man page.

Comment: I have this option set to `yes` and uncommented.

Comment: And did you restart sshd?

Comment: I didn't change this line. Maybe I was a bit unclear in my question. I've lost possibility to log via ssh when I configured sftp server. When I add my sftp server configuration in /etc/ssh/sshd_config I can use sftp but not ssh. When I comment out these configuration I can use ssh again.

Comment: Then undo the above and see if ssh works again, then debug from there.

Comment: The ForceCommand internal-sftp option will force sftp and prevent all ssh connections on any user in the group root. You have to look at doing it another way.

Comment: Well, if you have SFTP as root, you can very well just upload something, for example a /etc/crontab , that starts whatever service you want, including an SSH tunnel to a machine of your choice. You own that device, 100%.